# How to calculate the binomial probability when expected frequency is a random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution

I am trying to write a simple likelihood function to calculate the binomial probability of $X$ successes from $N$ trials. The problem is that the expected proportion of successes ($p_X$) is itself a binomially-distributed variable with $Y$ successes and $M$ trials.

That is, there a simple way to calculate $\text{E}(X)$ for $X\sim \text{Bin}(N, Y/M)$ when $Y\sim \text{Bin}(M, p)$?

Is it just the product of the two probabilities?

Comment: A binomial variable takes on values in ${0,1,2,\dots,M}$, and as such can't be an "expected proportion of successes".  Do you perhaps mean that $Y/M$ is the expected proportion of successes?  If so, this is an interesting model; could you explain a little how it comes about?

Comment: Yes, Y/M is the expected proportion of successes. I am a geneticist and observe a mutation at frequency q from N individuals in population 1.  From population 2, I observe the same mutation with frequency q from M individuals. I would like to calculate the probability of observing q (from N observations) conditional on the 'true' frequency being p. Of course, p is estimated with error so the binomial distribution doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Can you ask about your actual problem (at this stage you may want to ask a new question)? I'd give a different answer to that. Note that either you condition on the observed $p$ (as you do ... and then don't ... in your question here), or you throw out your present formulation of the problem and actually deal with what now seems to be the underlying question (which seems to be 'do the samples suggest the two population frequencies differ?') ... a completely different problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

$$\text{E} (X) = \text{E}_Y [ \text{E}_{X | Y} ( X | Y)]$$

Now $\text{E}_{X|Y}(X|Y)] = N\cdot p_x = N\cdot Y/M$, so

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{E} (X) &=& \text{E}_Y [ N\cdot Y/M]\\
             &=& \frac{N}{M}\cdot\text{E}_Y [Y]\\
             &=& \frac{N}{M}\cdot (Mp)\\
             &=& Np
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that E(X) = p; but the probability that E(X)=p is not just Bin(N,p), if p is a random variable itself, right?

Comment: Looks like you're getting muddled up. In the notation we have above, $p$ is the success probability for $Y$ and $Y/M$ (which is $p_X$) is the success probability for $X$. (You must distinguish those two probabilities; they're different values.)  $E(X)$ is the expectation of $X$ unconditional on information about $Y$. $E(X|Y)$ is the expectation of $X$ given you know the value of $Y$. Are you now making not just $p_X$ random but also $p$? Then what's it's distribution?

Comment: Alan, my earlier version omitted an important term; my apologies. Please take a look at the corrected answer. (That omission may have been part of the problem!)

Comment: p is binomial, too.

Comment: Can you change your question to reflect the distribution for $p$ as well, because as it's written up there presently, $p$ is not random; my answer only answers the question that's actually there. Nevertheless, recursive application of the same law, properly applied, yields the answer for that case as well.

Comment: Also, would you mind also explaining the context in which such a three-stage-binomial question arises, if possible? Binomial-binomials is astonishing enough (binomial-hypergeometric, perhaps, or beta-binomial, sure, and so by extension even beta-binomial-hypergeometric), but binomial-binomial-binomial? How does that happen? I can't see any very plausible sampling situations for it, so having an application would be very useful.

Comment: Okay - let me try again.  In a particular population, I observe a mutation frequency of 70% from a sample of 10 individuals. From prior evidence, I expect the mutation to be at 50% based on a sample of 10 individuals. It seems straight forward to calculate the probability of observing mutation frequency of 70% if the true freq. is 50%.  This is Pr(X=7)~Bin(10, .5) = ~11%. Intuitively, this seems wrong because my estimate of the true frequency has its own error associated with it. Somehow, I think that the law of total probability would be useful here.

Comment: I understand why you'd want a distribution on $p$, but why would the true p be *binomial*, though? That's discrete. Can't the underlying probability, $p$ take *any* value in some range (i.e. isn't it continuous?). And really, that's only two stages. Where does both $p_X$ and $p$ being binomial come in?